# How would I use RETURN in this situation? (discord.js bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make something where people have to pay to use a set of commands. I got that part down but I'm pretty sure I'm having troubles with the `return` function.

The code below makes it so it sends the error message, and then right after sends the command output! I want it to just send the error message if their user IDs aren't in the array. If their IDs are in the array, send the normal command usage (by using `return`, right?)

[image: This is what a user who's not on the gold members array sees.]

^^ This is what a user who's not on the gold members array sees. I want it so people's ID who I add will only show the command output. People who aren't in that User ID array will see the error (Whoops) message.

````js
var Spark = require("sparkbots")
const Permission = Spark.permission("Golds")
Permission.setLevel(5)
module.exports = Permission;

Permission.code = (client, message) => {
    let golds = ['190916650143318016']
    if(!golds.includes(message.author.id)){
      return message.reply("Whoops! That's a ⭐ GOLD ⭐ user only command. Purchase gold here: https://willm.xyz/dis/gold")

    } else {
      return false }
}```
````

Comment: You should also share the function that's calling the `Permission.code` one.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `For ... of ...` loop. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) is some information

```js
// here is an example
arr = ['1', '2', '3']
for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs 1, 2, 3
}
```

so for what you need to do is to put your if statement inside a for loop

```js
let golds = ['ID', 'ID2', 'ID3']
for (let i of golds) {
  if( i === message.author.id)){
    // if in gold
  }
  else {
    // if not in gold
  }
}
```